# D3 Scale / Ticks - include min and max

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create some tick marks on a range slider.

I'd like to be able to provide a min and max year and have D3 or some other lib create an appropriate amount ticks between the two years.

Furthermore i need to always include the max number as the last tick mark.

This is what i have (the 10 would be dynamic i imagine)

```
  const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1970, 2018]);
  const ticks = x.ticks(10);
```

The above outputs

```
[1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015]
```

Comment: So what was the difficulty you ran into?

Comment: The difficulty is the linear scale depending on the amount of ticks required combined with the range created doesn’t always return the max in the tick marks. The above tick marks max out at 2015, if I provide a min of 1970 and a max of 2018 I need 2018 (the max) to be always included in the tick marks. ... is that any clearer 

Comment: @Paulie Please edit your question to include those details -- it is much easier for potential question answerers if all the information is in the same place. Not everyone reads the comments. Thanks!

Comment: By 'range slider', do you mean `<input type='range'>`, or are you using a d3 axis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale.nice` before call ticks. Which produce

`[1970,1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2015,2020]`

```js
const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1970, 2018]).nice();
const ticks = x.ticks(10);

console.log(ticks)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```